# Set Email Attachment name in C#

Tags: c#, email, attachment, email-attachments

I add an attachment like this:

```
System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(AttachmentPath);   
msg.Attachments.Add(attachment);
```

But I want to make it attach as a different name, the actual file name is very long and confusing I would like it to attach  as "file.txt", is there an easy way to do this without having to make a copy of the file?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

How about:

```
System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(attachmentPath);
attachment.Name = "file.txt";  // set name here
msg.Attachments.Add(attachment);
```

Comment: This is what worked for me: attachment.ContentDisposition.FileName = "file.txt";

Answer (score 7):

You need to load the attachment from a stream and then you can give it a name and a media type.

```
var fs = new FileStream("attachmentPath", FileMode.Open);
var attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(fs, "MyAttachmentName.txt", "text/text");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var attachment = new Attachment(path){
    Name = "File Name"
};
msg.Attachments.Add(attachment);
```

So what I did was basically to create the attachment and add the name in the initialization.